# Are there cron jobs in sequelize js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Is there a way of implementing a deletion of a record after a specific time period in sequelize.js?

I didn't manage to find something like cron-jobs in the docs, however I stumbled across `hooks` which I guess may be the solution, but I'm not sure...

My goal is to have records that are older than **x minutes/hours/etc.** to be deleted automatically

Comment: What about a `setInterval` in your `app,js` ..? (or whatever your main thread is called)

Comment: @davidkonrad, thank you for your advice. After some research I came to a conclusion that there's no way a cron job can be implemented using sequelize.js. The only option is to use special packages or setInterval